# Can't see created folder in react native app (android)

Tags: android, react-native, filesystems

I connected android device to PC, uploaded folder with files to internal storage.
    `file:///sdcard/MyFolder`
When I try to read this directory from react-native application I can't see this folder

```
let storage = yield RNFS.readdir('file:///sdcard/')
console.log(storage)
```

This log shows other folders in directory but not the one I've just created from PC. Also files wrote from application are not visible on PC, but I can see it from application and android file explorer.
I stuck with this problem, can't find help on github issue for a week.

I use react-native-fs 2.5.1, react-native 0.48.0 on Android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, the path was incorret. When I changed it to `file:///storage/emulated/0/MyFolder` I saw files. But I still can't see files that my application has created. Only after device reboot, but this is another question.

I'm new to android file system and hope this answer will help someone else someday.